# Why 16.04.4 packages are older than of 16.04.1 packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, versions

How to read the Ubuntu version information there? Because to me it seems that newer release is targeted with an older `PHP sqlite` version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both `7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` [[1]](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/php7.0-sqlite3/7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) and `7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4` [[2]](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/php7.0-sqlite3/7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) have been released. So the newer version of `7.0.15` which is `7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4` takes over, while the only available revision of `7.0.18` is: `7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`.

so if I run:

```
apt-cache madison php7.0-sqlite3 | grep -iv source
```

I will get:

```
php7.0-sqlite3 | 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
php7.0-sqlite3 | 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
php7.0-sqlite3 | 7.0.4-7ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

and to see which version is candidate for  installation:

```
apt-cache policy php7.0-sqlite3
```

You'll see that the candidate version for installation is: `7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`.

You can check published versions [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/php7.0-sqlite3) which are:

```
php7.0-sqlite3 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 in amd64 (Security)
php7.0-sqlite3 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 in amd64 (Updates)
php7.0-sqlite3 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 in amd64 (Proposed)
```